# Directive inside partial appears with a bar on top

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating an UI using Angular on the front end. I have a directive which is the `navbar`. Since I am using ngRoute, I have used that directive inside my partial for `/home`. Everything works fine, but the navbar does not start from the top of the page. Instead there is a small pane below which the navbar starts. I want it to be something like how the stack overflow navbar in the top is.

This is my index.html

```
<body>
<ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
```

I've tried by using ng-view inside div but still it does not work.

home.html

```
<nav-bar></nav-bar>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="well well-sm">{{flashMessage}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-3 well pre-scrollable scroll-pane">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>
                <a href="#toparentnode">
                    ..
                </a>
                <br/>
                <p>nodes list goes here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 pre-scrollable scroll-pane">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered wrap-table text-center">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Value1</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></button>
                                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Value2</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></button>
                                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Value3</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></button>
                                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Value4</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></button>
                                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

navbar.html ( which is the templateUrl for navBar directive )

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#/">
            <img style="max-width:100px; margin-top: -7px;" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo"> 
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#/home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I have used `Twitter bootstrap` and one css named `signin.css` which is one found in the official website example - [css](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/signin.css)

This is the unnecessary pane in the top
[image]

But I want it to look like how stack overflow has the navbar.

I've tried adding the navbar directly to the main index.html and it works as expected. This unnecessary pane appears only when I use it as a directive. Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

from CSS try removing

```
body {
 padding-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, now its in the top. Since this css in used for the login page, removing this also moved my login form to the top. Can I create a class which I can apply only to the login form ?

Comment: Ok , set it to 0 then

Comment: doing it without seeing actual output is hard, but I would guess that the signin form relies on that space ( `padding-top` ) , is this correct?

Comment: Thanks but the 2nd answer below does the job without modifying the css. Can you tell me how to centre the elements in the navbar to the centre like in stack overflow bar. My navbar runs from extreme left to extreme right. Should I add some padding ?

Comment: I'm willing to add above change in a separate css for navbar.

Comment: You could add `padding-left` `padding-right` on `nav` selector , but usually a wrapper is used (mainly for full width background and responsive - like SO's navbar). If that solves your issue let me know

Comment: Well, yes I would like to make my navbar look like SO's . Can you please tell me where I should be adding it ?

Answer (score 0):

**ViChU** Hi there. 
Can you give this a try to see if it helps you here.

Add `navbar-fixed-top`

`<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">`

Comment: Still doesn't work. The padding in the top does not go.

Comment: Hi, when you added this did you also remove the **navbar-default**? and have you checked you have not added something in your css?

Comment: yes, added navbar-default along with this. and did not make any changes to the css. Still I got the same result.

Comment: No, I'm saying you just need to only use inverse OR default not both.  As soon as you add `navbar-fixed-top` it should/will fix to the top and the body will start under the navbar, so usually you would add 50px padding-top to the body move what is at the very top in the body. Can you try again and copy/paste the line of code I posted above for the **nav**.

Comment: Yes, this works :) . I did not remove the navbar-default. I removed that and added 60px padding. Now it works .. Can u tell me what navbar-fixed-top does ??

Comment: Great that it works now for you. Sure, navbar-fixed-top would use `position:fixed;` and `top:0;` and probably `left:0;`and `right:0;`